# How to show selected name in angular material multi select checkbox and chips component

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-chip

I'm using multi select checkbox with angular material chip. I have array objects with name and id, name is supposed to be displayed if user select options and id must be sent to backend. When I assign `[value]="topping.id"`, its showing selected id instead of name. How I can show name in UI when user select option and keep id in `formControl`? I have added demo link here.

**Image 1: Current result**

**Image 2: Expected result**

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-fwh6ns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.css)

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
<mat-select [formControl]="toppingsControl" multiple>
   <mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-chip-list>
         <mat-chip
         *ngFor="let topping of toppingsControl.value"
         [removable]="true"
         (removed)="onToppingRemoved(topping)">
         {{ topping }}
         <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
         </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
   </mat-select-trigger>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping.id">
     {{topping.name}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
toppingsControl = new FormControl([]);

toppingList: any[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Extra cheese' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mushroom' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Onion' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Sausage' }
];

 onToppingRemoved(topping: string) {
    const toppings = this.toppingsControl.value as string[];
    this.removeFirst(toppings, topping);
    this.toppingsControl.setValue(toppings); // To trigger change detection
  }

  private removeFirst<T>(array: T[], toRemove: T): void {
    const index = array.indexOf(toRemove);
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

**Current Result (image 1):**
[image]

**Expected Result (image 2):**
[image]

1. List item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the following line of code:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping.id">
```

You are telling angular to use the id as value for the form control values. A solution would be to instead of using only the id, map these ids to topping objects themselves. Then your control is using topping objects instead of only a number. Here is the code you need to change:

```
  <mat-chip
          *ngFor="let topping of idsToToppings(toppingsControl.value)"
          [removable]="true"
          (removed)="onToppingRemoved(topping.id)"
        >
          {{ topping.name }}
```

and add the following method in your component:

```
  idsToToppings(ids: number[]) : any[] {
    return ids.map((id) => {
      return this.toppingList.find((t) => t.id == id);
    });
  }
```

Comment: remove function is not working with this code? @Guillaume
You may try in demo code

Comment: I updated my answer. Remove should work now.